# How to force Android Studio `see` source in other flavours, so refactoring of abstract classes would be safer

Tags: java, android, class, polymorphism, android-studio

I have few abstract classes which has different implementations in flavors.

How do I make Android Studio find if method is used/overridden in all flavors.

Might be, that in currently selected flavor method might look unused.

Comment: The issue still persists, but I found some workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884947/refactoring-inside-the-main-source-set-doesnt-propagate-to-inactive-build-varia)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We haven't implemented refactoring/analysis across flavors or build types yet. You can track this at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66072