# Refactoring inside the main source set doesn't propagate to inactive build variants

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have `src/main/java` for the main source set. Also a `src/heroes/java` source set for a product flavor named `heroes` and a `src/villains/java` source set for a product flavor named `villains`.

Those have only a single build type, `debug`. Meaning the build variants pane will contain `heroesDebug` and `villainsDebug`.

Now, in Android Studio, if I select build variant `heroesDebug`, `src/main` and `src/heroes` become "active" while `src/villains` "deactivates". Meaning I can use ALT + Insert, code complete, and other such features of the IDE on those "active" source sets. Things like syntax highlighting won't even show on files inside an "inactive" source set.

And that's mostly fine. But I'll have a huge problem if I rename or move a lot of classes in `src/main` that are imported in many places within `src/villains`. I've noticed that the refactored package or class names reflect in `src/heroes` but when I switch to `villainsDebug`, I'll see red lines and `Cannot resolve symbol` errors in `src/villains` where the IDE should've updated the new names or locations of packages or classes!

That also works in reverse — if `villainsDebug` is active and I reshuffle some code in `src/main`, the changes will propagate to `src/villains` but if I again switch to `heroesDebug`, those changes will be nowhere to be seen.

**EDIT**

So how do I get changes in `src/main` to propagate to all the other source sets of "inactive" build variants?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of how will your changes like?

Comment: An example of that is if I move classes inside a package within `src/main` to another package within `src/main`. The new paths to those new classes won't propagate to inactive source sets. Like yesterday I had to move a package in `src/main` that had upto 12 classes. The new paths to those classes got reflected in `src/heroes`, but not in `src/villains`!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to take the advantage of IDE refactoring feature and expect this feature to apply to source code of inactive build variants. Hmm, if you just want to relocate those "shared" sources now and then, probably you can add additional source sets which is independent on build variants.

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Comment: All code in `src/main` is what you call "shared" sources. All code in `src/main` is needed in all other product flavors — otherwise if some code was only for `src/heroes`, then it'd be in `src/heroes` and not in `src/main`.

Answer (score 2):

try to add this in your apps build.gradle :

```
android{
...
    sourceSets{
        main{
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'heroes', 'villains']
        }
    }
}
```

this will cause all directories to be visible and you should do this only while refactoring and then remove this afterwards, because you will see duplicate class exceptions. Also this will create a weird Android project view, with multiple java folders. Probably not the best solution, but it worked for me

Comment: In our project, every flavor has it's own package (f.e. `com.example.app.villains` and `com.example.app.heroes`) so we don't have the problem of duplicate classes.
Because of that, we keep this `sourceSet` active all the time, but only for `debug` instead of `main`. Also, we are using `java.srcDirs += ['src']`.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do I get all source sets to be "active" irregardless of what build variant I've selected?

From IDE point of view, this is impossible at the current Android Studio (3.1.4) release, and I think this is a per design feature which is reasonable. Because, your source sets are supposed to be isolated according to build variants and should not impact on each other.

If you just want to relocate those "shared" sources now and then, probably you can add additional source sets which is independent on build variants, it will be something like below.

```
sourceSets {

    String sharedSources = "$projectDir/src/sharedSources/java"

    main {

    }

    heroes {
        java.srcDirs += sharedSources
    }

    villains {
        java.srcDirs += sharedSources
    }
}
```

So, your directory structure will be as below, but "sharedSources" is NOT a build variant here.

```
app
├── src
│   ├── heroes
│   ├── heroesDebug
│   ├── heroesRelease
│   ├── villains
│   ├── villainsDebug
│   ├── villainsRelease
│   ├── sharedSources // NOT indicating a build variant. Move those classes out to here.
│   └── main
```

Comment: Of course, build variants being made totally isolated makes sense. But it makes no sense with the main source set — which is not isolated from any product flavor, and no product flavor is isolated from `src/main`. So ideally changes should propagate from `src/main` to all product flavors, but never between product flavors. If I can't do it with the IDE, how can I hack past this limitation?

Comment: All code in src/main is what you call "shared" sources. All code in `src/main` is needed in all other product flavors — otherwise if some code was only for `src/heroes`, then it'd be in `src/heroes` and not in `src/main`.

Comment: Upvote for showing me what's possible with Gradle. But I don't really see how that's different with my current directory structure. `main` is also not a build variant. So creating `sharedSources` is pointless when `main` is effectively doing the same job.

Comment: It looks weird to move around your source code here and there for different build variants, maybe I misunderstood your problem and what's your objective.